# Which fopen() mode should i use when working with a .wav file?

Tags: c, wav

I am using `fPointInput = fopen(fileName, "r");`, when trying to access the data chunk inide the .WAV file but never getting any comprehensible results. (Data array is filled mostly with zeroes except the first few hundred indices). Can this be caused by the usage of inaccurate opening mode ?

Comment: You probably want to open it with `rb` since it's a binary file. You can use `rb+` if you want to receive a error when opening the file.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Binary vs text mode only really matters on Windows. And could you show the code you're using to read `fPointInput`?

Comment: @tversteeg `rb+` isn't about error handling. `rb+` will open it for both reading and writing, which they probably don't want to do.

Comment: i am working on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://truelogic.org/wordpress/2015/09/04/parsing-a-wav-file-in-c/) indicates that using `rb` works well.
Note that nothing in this answer is `Windows` specific. Just standard `C` IO.

Comment: Unix does not distinguish between "text" and "binary" files. So `b` does nothing. However, to make your code cross platform you should use `b` where appropriate. That code uses a 1K buffers to get the current working directory and filename. It should instead use `MAXPATHLEN` from `sys/param.h`. But at least it protects itself from a buffer overflow.